# How to describe word with many syllables

Tags: vocabulary

How do we describe a word that has many *syllables*?

For example, what's the correct way to rewrite the sentence below?

> However these names end up being very long both visually and
>   pronunciationally.

Comment: Personally I'd go with "However, these names end up being very long."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you looking for [polysyllabic](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/polysyllabic)?

Comment: Is this sentence OK: "*However these names end up being very long visually and polysyllabic.*" I'm not sure why but it sounds a bit weird.

Comment: I think that sounds ok. Nice word.

Comment: No, I find that sentence a bit pleonastic.  I would write "these names end up being polysyllabic".  Although it's hard to know whether that makes sense in your context, when you've only given us a single sentence.

Comment: "these names end up being polysyllabic" seems to mean "these names end up having more than one syllable. What I want to express is "these names end up requiring a ton of syllables to fully pronounce them".

Comment: Barrie England has what you want then. *sesquipedalian*, from L. *sesquipedalia verba* "words a foot-and-a-half long". http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=sesquipedalian

Comment: Maybe just "these names end up long and hard to say".

Comment: @Pacerier, you could qualify it: "overly polysyllabic" or "too polysyllabic".

Answer (score 4):

If you seek to impress, you could try *sesquipedalian*. (There is, by the way, no adverb from *pronunciation*.)

Comment: I don't know how much it will impress; I've only ever seen it used in criticism (having that "turnabout is fair play" quality of communicating, "This is the affectation you portray when you use stupidly big words.")  But I think that, using common endings, a big word would be a sesquiped, writing with lots of big words would be sesquipedal and would display the attribute of sesquipedality, and the writing itself and the person who wrote it could be accused of being sesquipedalian.

Comment: If you *really* want to impress, how about tripedalian? That's twice as long.

Comment: [Hippopotomonstrosesquipedalian?](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hippopotomonstrosesquipedalian)

Answer (score 3):

The construct in your question is indeed a bit awkward. You could rephrase it as *These names end up being too long, both to look at (write) and to pronounce.*

Answer (score 0):

I think I would say, ”These names end up being too long and awkward (of speech*),” with the assumption that defining the indirect object of the adverbs negates the purpose of being sententious, or pithy.

*contingent upon the audience

Answer (score 0):

**mouthful/It's a mouthful**

**mouthful**

> A very long word or phrase [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mouthful)

---

> *"I love this word because **it's a mouthful**, but it sounds go together wonderfully."*
>
> **skullduggery**
>
> (skul-DUG-ah-ree)
>
> *noun*
>
> unscrupulous or deceptive behavior; trickery. [R.H. Fiske; *The Best
> Words*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Best_Words/-5Ib6NMcfpkC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=it%27s%20a%20mouthful%20word&pg=PT203&printsec=frontcover)